# print value from php webservice (json object)

Tags: php, arrays, json

From a webservice, I receive a json object.

var_dump from json_decode ($getUsercodes, true)  gives me:

```
Array(549) {
["Jackson Kim"]=> array(2) { ["codeA"]=> string(1) "x" ["codeB"]=> string(1) "y" } 
["Richardson"]=> array(2) { ["codeA"]=> string(1) "x" ["codeB"]=> string(1) "y" } 
["Jenson Webb"]=> array(2) { ["codeA"]=> string(1) "x" ["codeB"]=> string(1) "y" } 
["Makai Pate"]=> array(2) { ["codeA"]=> string(1) "x" ["codeB"]=> string(1) "y" } ....
```

The same -> var_dump from json_decode ($getUsercodes, false)  gives me:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (549) {
["Jackson Kim"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["codeA"]=> string(1) "x" ["codeB"]=> string(1) "y" } 
["Richardson"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["codeA"]=> string(1) "x" ["codeB"]=> string(1) "y" } 
["Jenson Webb"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["codeA"]=> string(1) "x" ["codeB"]=> string(1) "y" } 
["Makai Pate"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["codeA"]=> string(1) "x" ["codeB"]=> string(1) "y" } 
....
```

How can I print only the first name? 'Jackson Kim'

I've tried:

```
$result = json_decode ($getUsercodes, true)

echo $result[0]
```

It gives me undefined offset?

Comment: Your keys seems to be the actual values that you wish to output, as a result, consider a loop.

Comment: use foreach loop then you can access values easy.

Comment: If you generate the JSON that is returned I suggest you reorganise how you do that so the data is in a more sensible and usable state

Comment: @IIIo, did you try any of these answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$result = json_decode ($getUsercodes, true);
reset($array);  // This function reset array index to 1st member.
$first_key = key($array);  // This function returns first index of the array where the pointer is.
echo $first_key;  // So, this will print the first name
```

To get further keys: Please check out this example.

```
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

echo current($people) . "<br>"; // Will print 'Peter'
echo next($people) . "<br>"; // Will print 'Joe'
echo next($people) . "<br>"; // Will print 'Glenn'
echo reset($people); // Will print 'Peter'
```

Comment: Good answer. FYI, `reset()` here is not required ([example](https://3v4l.org/BUSEq))

Comment: Thank you @Syscall, I know `reset()` is not required right now. But put it there for full reference.

Comment: lets see if OP tries with the answer and accepts it.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works :) How can I get the second name or the fifth name?  My key seems indeed the acual value that I need. It's very confusing.  Thanks!!!

Comment: I tried to get further indexes you can use `next()`. I am updating my answer for your additional question. Can you accept my answer and up vote it for the original quesiton please?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the first key value of the array

```
$result = json_decode ($getUsercodes, true)   
$first_value = reset($result);
```